# Stripes Framework Validation on Custom Dynamic Form

Tags: java, validation, frameworks, stripes

**Introduction**

I am developing application using Stripes Framework.  Stripes has possibility to declare un-form variables, which is possible to access direct variable either in html and ActionBean using getter and setter.

Example in ActionBean

```
class UserActionBean implements ActionBean {

    @Validate(...)
    int userid;
    @Validate(...)
    int name;

    int getUserid() { ... }
    int setUserid(int userid) { ... }
}
```

Example in HTML

```
<input type="text" name="userid" ... />
```

But, this approach take many code to declare variable one-by-one.

To avoid it, I create one variable **Map post = new HashMap<>()** to accept all the input from html to ActionBean, as shown example below:

```
<input type="text" name="post['userid']" ... />
```

And access on ActionBean

```
Integer userid = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(post.get("userid")));
```

Unfortunately, I can't use Stripes Validation for this approach.  Example content of *post.get("userid")* cannot validate. To enable validation, I am using JQuery validation.

**Question**

I need to provide not just JQuery validation but also server validation.  I search on Stripes framework (github) to extends validation, *but still has no idea to build extends of validation to meet my requirement*.

Current alternative, I build my own server validation, not follow stripes.

Please advice to enable me to extends Stripes Validation on my case. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is setup a `validate` method such as

```
@HandlesEvent(value = "validate")
public Resolution validate () throws ResponseException {

    // check validation, if failed throw Exception

    // else
    return null;
}
```

This will be called first from `Jquery.ajax` and then on the `jquery` success block call the real method